# How to make this JS image compare responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive

I've been making a JS image compare based on [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_image_compare). And whatever I do, it's not responsive (I can't use any frameworks for this). I've tried changing the .img-comp-slider width to 100%, as in:

```
.img-comp-slider {
width: 100%;
height: /custom height here/;
}
```

As well as .img-comp-img img. But that doesn't help when the screen is resized.

I suspect that the issue might lie in JS code, But I can't be sure because I'm not very good with it.

Can someone help me out? Is there an approach that could make this responsive? Thanks!

Comment: You should post code that you have tried or more of what you are doing.  You posted one style which isn't really helpful.  But I would suggest using js to update the heights of your images and the div they are contained in.  You would do this on resize.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. What I tried was all CSS based, because I know very little JS so it's difficult to figure out what needs to be changed. I tried updating the width in js to percentages and while that did solve some of the issues, the arrow was moving around when the screen was resized. I will update my answer with that as well. @Cruril

Answer (score 0):

Here is more or less your solution of img compare responsiveness.

```
.img-comp-container {
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
}
.img-comp-container img {
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
}
```

The necessary JavaScript:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    width = $(".img-comp-container").find('img').width()
    height = $(".img-comp-container").find('img').height();
    $(".img-comp-slider").css( "top", height/2 );
    $(".img-comp-slider").css("left" ,width/2);

});
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mutafaf/24nd3wo6/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. The only thing is that when the window is resized, the front image and the button move around too. Is there a way to fix that?